# Dynamic row and column header change using jsp/html

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, displaytag

I need to prepare a table in which row and column headers are dynamic. Previously i was using struts display tag for displaying details from DB. Now since column headers are also varying in the requirement ...any suggestions on what to use would be appreciated.

Currently am working with struts, jsp and Oracle db for this requirement.

The objective is to display a summary report with headers like below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `Struts2-jQuery` Plugin, and an `sjGrid` ?

http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action

(click on Grid and on left menu to view all the showcases)